# dcos package install - resource request declined due to no port need?

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesosphere, dcos

I am following https://docs.konghq.com/install/dcos to install kong on my newly setup DCOS cluster. However I am blocked at the step **Deploy Marathon-LB**.

The service cannot be deployed because there is no resource offer. But when I look at **Debug** I see something that doesn't add up: Why `Requested: N/A` does not warrant the port resource??

[image]